# how to fix "Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics' "

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, angular7

I am trying to update Angular. So I ran `ng update --all` from CMD in my Angular project that I created with vs-2015 and in return I got another error in my project:

> Error TS2345  Argument of type '{ imports: typeof BrowserModule[];
>   declarations: typeof AppComponent[]; bootstrap: typeof AppComp...' is
>   not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'.
>
> Property 'true' is missing in type '{ imports: typeof BrowserModule[]; 
>   declarations:
>   typeof AppComponent[]; bootstrap: typeof AppComp...'.
>
> TypeScript Virtual Projects   c:\users\lesibamo\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\Angular4demo\Angular4demo\src\app\app.module.ts 6   Active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Delete your `package-lock.json` file
2. Delete Node `node_modules` folder in your angular project
3. open your command promt and navigate your Angular project folder, type `npm update`
4. Confirm the Angular version by `ng --version`
5. Run your project `ng serve` if update success the project should load without error

Comment: this fixed migration to angular 9 where angular-devkit was only referenced in `package-lock.json`